# fetch does not work in react ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

as the titles say, the following does not work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class MDComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {contacts: []};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/EntityType',  {
            headers:{
                "Accept": "application/json",
            }
        })
            .then((res) => {return res.json()})
            .then(data =>
            {this.setState({ contacts: data.toString() })})
            ;
    }



    render() {
        return(
            <div> hello {this.state.contacts}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default MDComponent;
```

in browsers I always see "hello", in inspector I see a successful GET request to the `http://localhost:8080/EntityType` with a valid json response,

what is the problem?

**update:** logs from firefox when I execute a fetch in its developer consol:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/EntityType. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Comment: Why are you using this `.toString()`? Isn't `contacts` supposed to be  an array?

Comment: can you show an example of the json response you see in network tab?

Comment: that is not important, even if I change `this.setState({ contacts: data.toString() })` to `this.setState({ contacts: 'Mehrdad' })` I again only see hello.

Comment: it seems that part of fetch never execute

Comment: After `.then(data =>`, could you add `console.log(data)` and tell me what you get

Comment: I added `.catch(console.error);` after `.then(..`, nothing shows in terminal, i used npm start for running this app.

Comment: now I managed to see error by puting `.catch(r=>{this.setState({contacts: r.toString()})})`, it says: `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

Comment: I guess it would be a cors error, you could try to set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for your dev environment.

Comment: I again see a successful GET request to the resource with a valid JSON response!!

Comment: How is it a Network Error while the request was successful?

Comment: I updated the question. how to disable cors?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CORS problem.

I added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` to my spring Controller method, and the problem solved.